# “May I know your good name?”

Tags: adjectives, politeness, subcontinental-english

"*May I know your good name*” is a typically Indian way of honouring another person by asking their name using an adjective like *sweet, good, beautiful,* et cetera. Of course there won’t ever be any *bad* or *sour* name (unless we feel it such) when asking.

If this manner of asking someone’s name is incorrect or inappropriate, then how could I make it sound more polite and amicable without negotiating the basic principles of English?

Comment: Is this face-to-face, on the telephone, online...? (Not every convention is applicable to every environment)

Comment: Sounds rather Dickensian, perhaps even something out of Dumas. *“Pray good sir, might you do me the honour of bringing me to know your good name, that I might better remember the pleasure of your fine company when we have parted?”*

Comment: Saying just 'What is your name?' in any context might be a little blunt. For official things, like when registering, 'Can I have your name, please?' is the most common and straightforward. At a party, one usually says 'I didn't catch your name." whether you were introduced or not.

Comment: Or you might say, "Who's speaking, please?" when on the phone. Each situation has its own convention.

Comment: But you can get away with _“May I know your good name?”_ in  the U.S, anyway, **provided** you deliver it in an Indian-English accent. With the smile and the head wag, if in person.

Comment: @Mitch Using *can* in that way is always pushy and demanding — and therefore, lacking in courtesy.  Soften it with *could* or *may*.

Comment: @tchrist: oh yes, I was channeling more the DMV attitude. Maybe 'Would you mind if...' would be better?

Comment: There are contexts where you can say *"Might I ask your name, Sir/Madame?"* without it being perceived as "strange", but I don't think you can fit anything like "good" in there without sounding tiresomely obsequious and/or like a foreigner trying to replicate their own native forms in a culture where they don't really fit. The best I can think of is *"Would you be good enough to tell me your name?"*

Comment: Or seal the request with the "magic" word, *please*, as in ***"What is your name, please?"***

Comment: The other approach is to say, "I'm Vibhas Kulkarni." and hold out your hand (in preparation to shake) and wait.  If he wants to tell you his name that's his opportunity to do so.

Comment: Surprising that nobody picked up on the actual meaning of _good name_ in Indian English (as a direct translation of Hindi _subh naam_): the first part of your official full name. See also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47149/when-someone-in-india-asks-for-my-good-name-what-are-they-expecting

Answer (score 12):

As @tchrist noted in a comment, *may I know your good name?* sounds overly old fashioned to a native English speaker.

When you're encountering a stranger, a common way to get someone's name is to provide yours first, *especially after conversation has already been initiated*. This conversation usually goes something like:

> Aaron: I don't think I know your name. Mine is Aaron.
>
> John: [My name is] John. It's nice to meet you.
>
> Aaron: Nice to meet you, too.

And then two would shake hands. Generally speaking, it would be rude for John (in this example) to not respond by providing his name.

Answer (score 2):

I often use "I'm sorry, I didn't catch [or get] your name," even when I know it hasn't been offered yet. I preface that with repeating my own name, if it isn't obvious in context.

Answer (score 0):

Ask for it cheerfully and congenially (basically means relaxed and friendly). I really can't think of anything past that. A friendly face goes a long way in English. It transmits the same idea, and if the other person doesn't trust your face, he probably isn't going to trust the adjective good, either.

Also, if he doesn't know your name, saying "My name is..." and then asking will help as well.

Comment: I should imagine a friendly face goes a long way not just in English but in any language, or even none at all.

Comment: Yeah, definitely :)

Answer (score -2):

Asking for a name is not a traditional form of greeting in English. As far as I understand your question you are asking what conventional English way of greeting might be equivalent to the Indian *may I know your good name*.

In English when the person is unknown to you would be –

How do you do.

From OED –

> how-do-you-do | how-d'ye-do, phr. and n
>
> n. Used as a name for the inquiry (which is often used as a mere greeting or salutation)